# Obtaining top most node in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I do have relationship like following, through my Cypher query I'm beginning with `Segment1` and getting relationships accordingly.

```
(Segment1)-[:Leaf]->(Op1)-[:Account]->(Ac2)-[:Parent]->(Acc1)-[:Parent]->(Acc)
```

I want to get the top most node of `[:Parent]` relationship hierarchy. Is there any way to obtain it?

Note: I need obtain this without using loops in Cypher because this is only a part of my query.

**Expected Output**

```
(Acc)
```

Please help me to figure out this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will work:

```
MATCH (Segment1)-[:Leaf]->(Op1)-[:Account]->(Ac2)-[*:Parent]->(Acc)
WHERE NOT (Acc)-[:Parent]->()
RETURN Acc;
```

Unlike @logisma's solution, this query should be more performant, since it immediately ignores all `Acc` candidates that have an outgoing `Parent` relationship (instead of determining the size of the entire outgoing path).

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should work:

```
MATCH ({name:'Segment1'})-[:Leaf|:Account|:Parent*]->(b)
WITH collect(b) as nodes
RETURN last(nodes)
```

This query start from a node with `name = 'Segment1'` and walk through relationships of types `:Leaf`, `:Account` and `:Parent` to `b`. After `b` is collected into a list with [collect()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) function. Then the last node in the list is returned. This is done by the [last()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-last) function.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this query :

```
MATCH (Segment1 {name:'Segment1'})-[:Leaf]->(Op1)-[:Account]->(Ac2)-[*:Parent]->(Acc)
WHERE size((Acc)-[:Parent]->()) = 0
RETURN Acc
```

Definition of the last [Parent] node is done by the WHERE clause.

Cheers